# Creating animated cartoons (2D and 3D)

Tags: video, animation

I am searching for an animation software (free if is possible) for creating 2D or 3D animations. For Windows, for Linux, or as Web app.

I want it to be simple to use (to have characters library and objects library) and to be easy to make animations with. I need a such program because I need to make the animations very fast.

I have tried Daz Studio, Pencil, iClone, WebCartoonMaker etc.

Comment: Online? If not, what OS?

Comment: Try [GoAnimate](http://goanimate.com/)

Comment: @JanDoggen Windows or Linux or Online